# Invoke component refresh in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, observable, auth0

I am trying to implement a navbar that shows different links based on whether or not a user is logged-in.

I am using the `angular2-jwt` library which provides the `tokenNotExpired()` function.

I have 2 routes, `/home` and `/login`. I have a navbar component which is outside of the `<router-outlet>`, which means it is initialized only once and not every time the route changes.

After successful login, I am invoking `router.navigate(['/home])`. The home and login both have checks for if a user is logged-in in their respective `ngOnInit()` functions. The home component is therefore able to detect the logged-in user.

However, I am unable to update the navbar since it is not informed of the login.

Could anyone please tell me the correct way to implement this change detection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expose login status via service

```ts
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService{
    userLoggedIn : bool = false;

    //call this function when login status changes
    changeLoginStatus(status: bool){
        this.userLoggedIn = status;
    }
}
```

make your service singleton

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
  ],
  providers: [UserAuthService], // <-- Provide your service here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

user your service in your navbar

```ts
import { UserAuthService } from 'path/to/service';

export class NavbarComponent {
    constructor(private authService: UserAuthService ) { } // <-- inject service

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

so you can change your template using service.

```html
<div [hidden]="!authService.userLoggedIn"><a routerLink="/login">login</a></div>
```

call `changeLoginStatus` function of the service when login status changes.

Comment: Thanks Sefa. Since I am using the `angular2-jwt` library so I have replaced `userLoggedIn : bool = false;` and the change function with a function that returns the output of `tokenNotExpired()`.

Comment: This does work. However, you are accessing the service variable directly from within the View like so: `[hidden]="!authService.userLoggedIn"`. Is this really the right way of doing this (I don't think so)? Were we not supposed to use BehaviorSubject and propagate the changes and subscribe to them via Navbar?