# angular2: category pipe between two components

Tags: angular

I have two separate components a navbar.component and a home.component. My links in the **navbar component** will be activated on `(click)="categoryFilter('foo')"` and the function would return the string value. Then I want to pass it from my **navbar.component** to a pipe located in my **home.component**.

I think I could achieve this by importing my whole navbar.component into my home.component but that is overkill since I'm just trying to return one value. Is there a better way to pass this variable from one component to another?

Comment: You can use services for that. See my answer at link and you can implement your own service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213694/invoke-component-refresh-in-angular-2/40213887#40213887

Comment: if you're using routing you could use a route parameter, if you're not and the components are side by side you could use inputs, local variable reference in the template, or even a DI service which holds the information you need.

Those are a few ways it can be tackled.

Comment: Cool Thanks guys, I actually got the idea of using the route after posting this question but I haven't done anything with it yet. I'll look into these options.